# Do I use a switch or if else to simplify this? jQuery

Tags: jquery, repeat, simplify

I tried using both switch and if else but I could not get it to work right. I want to not repeat myself this many times.

```
        $('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", ".date-edit", function () {
            var dateInput = jQuery(this).html("");
            $(".pop-up-box-date").dialog(dateInput);
        });

        $('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", ".radio-edit", function () {
            var radioInput = jQuery(this).html("");
            $(".pop-up-box-radio").dialog(radioInput);
        });

        $('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", ".checkbox-edit", function () {
            var checkboxInput = jQuery(this).html("");
            $(".pop-up-box-checkbox").dialog(checkboxInput);
        });

        $('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", ".dropdown-edit", function () {
            var dropdownInput = jQuery(this).html("");
            $(".pop-up-box-dropdown").dialog(dropdownInput);
        });

        $('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", ".telephone-edit", function () {
            var telephoneInput = jQuery(this).html("");
            $(".pop-up-box-telephone").dialog(telephoneInput);
        });

        $('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", ".button-edit", function () {
            var buttonInput = jQuery(this).html("");
            $(".pop-up-box-button").dialog(buttonInput);
        });

        $('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", ".textarea-edit", function () {
            var textareaInput = jQuery(this).html("");
            $(".pop-up-box-textarea").dialog(textareaInput);
        });
```

I am quite new to this so if there is a better way that I don't know please let me know. Thanks

Here is one of the HTML blocks:

```
<div class='pop-up-box-text' style='display: none;' Title="Edit Text Box">
    <p id="textTitle" class="pop-up-copy">Title</p><p class="pop-up-inputs"><input type='text' /></p>
    <p class="pop-up-copy">Textbox Placeholder</p><p class="pop-up-inputs"><input id="textbox" type='text' /></p>
    <div class="submit"><button id="subimt" class="submit">Submit</button></div>
</div>
```

The edit is located in this html replacement:

```
case 'btntype_text':
    jQuery('.ui-widget-content .' + fieldClass).html("
           <div class='drop-blank'>
              <p>Text Box</p>
              <div class='li-float'>
                  <input id='textPlaceholder' type='text' placeholder='Text' disabled/>
              </div>
              <div class='text-edit'></div>
              <div class='delete'></div>
           </div>");
    fieldType = "text";
    break;
```

Comment: You can start to simplify by not using `on()`. Since you're not delegating events, just use `click()`.

Comment: you know that `jQuery(this).html("")` deletes the content each time? you could also write `var buttonInput = ""`

Comment: Show us an example of one HTML block. My guess is that you can do it all with common classes and a single jQuery function.

Comment: I was using `jQuery(this).empty()` to delete content in other places, so if I just use `.html()` it will delete the content so I do not need `.empty()` ?

Comment: if you really need to address different targets on different triggering elements, you wont another chance than using `if`. i dont see how `switch` would come in handy here

Comment: Your sample html does not seem to have any element with class `-edit`. How come?

Comment: There seems to be a multi-step process and it appears to me that they are not clearly separated in your question. It sounds like you have a part where you add content to the DOM and there's a part where you set up event listeners. Can you clarify which part you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your naming convention is consistent, you can do this:

```
$('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", "[class$=edit]", function () {
     var input = jQuery(this).html("");
     $(".pop-up-box-" + this.className.match(/(\w+)-edit/)[1]).dialog(input);
});
```

I am making the assumption that you want to capture classes ending with `"edit"`, so we make use of *ending-with* selector and use some basic regex to get the specific class name.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing so would be like this:

```
$('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", function (e) {
   var target = $(e.target);
   if (target.is('.date-edit')) {
     // handle case
   } else if (target.is('.radio-edit')) {
     // handle case
   }
});
```

`Switch` statement would also work, even better in fact.

Comment: i am a fan of using several `if` blocks instead of `if else`

Comment: A `switch (e.target.className)` would be pretty faster than multiple ifs on a jQuery object

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the code just checking on the parent element, and then use the specific class to call your function. You can also use a regular expression to be more concise.

```
$('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", function (e) {
   var name = e.target.className.match(/\.(.*)\-/)[1];
   $(".pop-up-box-" + name).dialog(e.target.innerHTML); // or whatever you want
});
```

Answer (score 2):

- Give your elements a blanket class that you can use to target them in one swoop
- Use `data-*` attributes to define the popup that you will be working with.

If your edit button markup looks (something) like:

```
<button class="date-edit edit-button" data-popup="date">..</button>
<button class="radio-edit edit-button" data-popup="radio">..</button>
<!-- etc.. -->
```

Your jQuery would become:

```
$('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", ".edit-button", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        popup = $this.attr('data-popup');

    $(".pop-up-box-" + popup).dialog( $this.html() );
});
```

Already noted, but you are using the 'setter' version of `.html()` where I think you mean to be using the 'getter' version.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming HTML something like this:

```
<div class="ui-widget-content">
    <div class="edit date-edit"></div>
    <div class="content pop-up-box-date"></div>
</div>
```

You can use `each()` to handle them all at once:

```
$('div.ui-widget-content .edit').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.content').dialog( $(this).html() );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

These are all great answers. Let me offer one of my own, using an associative array.

With this method, you won't need to use any conditional operators. Your function is written only once, as are your selectors. The **input selector** refers to the element which will be assigned the click handler. The **target** refers to the element that will receive the input.

This method also allows you to abstract your functionality and simply maintain a list of paired selectors. You can make the list as long or short as needed without ever needing to modify the code.

**Code**

```
// Associative array of { input selector : target };
var target_classess = {
    ".date-edit" : ".pop-up-box-date",
    ".radio-edit" : ".pop-up-box-radio",
    ".checkbox-edit" : ".pop-up-box-checkbox",
    ".dropdown-edit" : ".pop-up-box-dropdown",
    ".telephone-edit" : ".pop-up-box-telephone",
    ".button-edit" : ".pop-up-box-button",
    ".textarea-edit" : ".pop-up-box-textarea"
};

// Gets keys of associative array as selectors.
var selectors = Object.keys(target_classes);

// Iterate through associative array.
for (i=0,c=target_classes.length;i<c;i++) {

    // Get this iteration's input selector.
    var selector = selectors[i];

    // Assign click handler for input selector.
    $('div.ui-widget-content').on("click", selector, function () {

        // Clear HTML, cache reference to element.
        var input = jQuery(this).html("");

        // Assign to target.
        $(target_classes[selector]).dialog(input);
    });    
}
```

While not directly related to your question, it is also worth mentioning (as others also have) that:

- The `$.click()` function in place of `$.on()` would simplify your code and
- The line `= jQuery(this).html("")` will remove all contained HTML before returning a reference to `this`.